# variable value in a backtracking solution is not going back to its original state

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

I was trying to build a solution to the problem of generating all possible combination of `k` of the length `n`

ex: k = 4, n = 2

output :

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 1]
[4, 2]
[4, 3]
[4, 4]
```

Here is the pseudocode for the logic that I implemented

```
def backTrack(arr):
    if length(arr) == k:
        return

    loop through from 1 to n <- for i in range(1, n+1):
        i = value of loop
        add i to an array variable arr <- arr.append(i)
        backtrack(arr) <- recurse
        remove last index value from arr <- arr = arr[:-1]
```

for this above code, I am supposed to get the following values

```
on depth 1:
   the loop starts with 1
   and arr = [1]
   
   then it recuses to depth 2
      the loop starts with 1
       and arr = [1, 1]
       since the length of arr = k =2 it wont recurse further and continue
       arr = arr[:-1] = arr = [1]

       then i will be 2 
       and arr = [1,2]
       similarly [1, 3] and [1, 4] and then it goes to depth 1 or the parent call

on depth 1
  value of i = 1
   and arr  = 1
   now, arr = arr[:-1] that makes arr = []
  and now i becomes 2 and the process continues
```

But debugging the code written with the following pseudo code, shows that on depth `1` the arr never get back to being `[1]` but become `[1, 1]` I am still struggling to understand why it is so.

Below is the debugging solution with the print statements

```
class Solution(object):
    def combine(self, n, k):
    
        def backTrack(arr, result, depth):
            if len(arr) == k:
                return
    
            for i in range(1, n + 1):
                arr.append(i)
                print("depth = " + str(depth) + ", i = " + str(i) + ", arr=" + str(arr))
                backTrack(arr, result, depth + 1)
            
                print("depth -> " + str(depth) + ", i-> " + str(i) + ", arr-> " + str(arr))
                arr = arr[:-1]

        
        return backTrack([], [], 1)



ob = Solution()
result = ob.combine(4, 2)
```

Below is the debugged output

```
depth = 1, i = 1, arr=[1]
depth = 2, i = 1, arr=[1, 1]
depth -> 2, i-> 1, arr-> [1, 1]
depth = 2, i = 2, arr=[1, 2]
depth -> 2, i-> 2, arr-> [1, 2]
depth = 2, i = 3, arr=[1, 3]
depth -> 2, i-> 3, arr-> [1, 3]
depth = 2, i = 4, arr=[1, 4]
depth -> 2, i-> 4, arr-> [1, 4]
depth -> 1, i-> 1, arr-> [1, 1] * going back to parent call arr never becomes 1
depth = 1, i = 2, arr=[1, 2]
depth -> 1, i-> 2, arr-> [1, 2]
depth = 1, i = 3, arr=[1, 3]
depth -> 1, i-> 3, arr-> [1, 3]
depth = 1, i = 4, arr=[1, 4]
depth -> 1, i-> 4, arr-> [1, 4]
```

I have marked the debugger output in `*` to show the state of the arr in the parent call never gets back to being `1`

I want to understand why it is so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr = arr[:-1]` creates a **new copy** of `arr` with the last element removed and assigns it to the local variable `arr`. This means that the `arr`s in other scopes of the recursive calls reference some other list which still has the last element.

You need to remove the last element from this list by writing `arr.pop()`.

If you need further explanation about mutable and immutables in python and why it works this way please comment.

Comment: thanks for that explanations, can you give further explanation on it. If arr = arr[:-1] is creating a local copy of arr, then how is it differentiating from the global arr by the same name !

Comment: `arr` is a reference (like a pointer) to a list. When you pass down `arr`, a copy of the pointer is sent down, but since the value of the pointer is the same, it points to the same object. Now, when you do `arr = arr[:-1]` you are creating a copy of the list. This is an entirely new object. The list that `arr` pointed to before remains unchanged. When the function returns, this new reference goes out of scope and since there are no other references to the new list, the garbage collector just removes it.

Comment: In other words, the immediate value of `arr` is just a refernce that points to the list object. This value/reference itself is local, but it points to something that is not local. If you keep that reference the same, every local copy of that referenc points to the same object. This the difference between mutable and immutable objects in python.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the implementation should look like based on your pseudo-code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def combine(self, n, k):
        total = []

        def backTrack(depth, stack):
            if depth >= k:
                total.append(stack[:])
                return

            for i in range(1, n + 1):
                stack.append(i)
                backTrack(depth + 1, stack)
                stack.pop()

        backTrack(0, [])
        return total
```

In your implementation this line of code `arr = arr[:-1]` does not remove anything from the list. In fact, it brakes the whole list by making it equal with the last element.